# How to do sum from the file and move in particular way in another file in linux?

Tags: linux, bash, sed

Acttualy this is my assignment.I have three-four file,related by student record.Every file have two-three student record.like this

```
Course Name:Opreating System
Credit: 4
123456 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 5 8 0 12 10 25
243567 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 7 9 12 15 17 15
```

Every file have different coursename.I did every coursename and studentid move 
in one file but now i don't know how to add all marks and move to another file on same place where is id? Can you please tell me how to do it?

It looks like this:

```
Student# Operating Systems JAVA C++ Web Programming GPA
123456       76             63   50       82        67.75
243567       80             -    34       63          59
```

I did like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

find ~/2011/Fall/StudentsRecord -name "*.rec" | xargs grep -l 'CREDITS' | xargs cat > rsh1

echo "STUDENT ID" > rsh2

sed -n /COURSE/p rsh1 | sed 's/COURSE NAME: //g' >> rsh2

echo "GPA" >> rsh2

sed -e :a -e '{N; s/\n/       /g; ta}' rsh2 > rshf

sed '/COURSE/d;/CREDIT/d' rsh1 | sort -uk 1,1 | cut -d' ' -f1 | paste -d' ' >> rshf
```

Comment: Please tag it with the language or tool you are using, and be sure to post what have you tried and a specific problem. We're here to answer, not to do your homework!

Comment: I asking you only one question.....How to do the sum and moving all sum on particular place?

Comment: Not sure if you're aware of, but this is a programming Q&A website, be sure to read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: Way better! Thanks for your edit and welcome to StackOverflow

Comment: Please do not vandalize your questions!

Comment: @user1050667 re: *I asking you only one question.....How to do the sum and moving all sum on particular place?* ...... ummmm, I believe that is two questions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some comments and a few pointers :

It would help to add 'comments' for each line of code that is not self evident ; i.e. code like `mv f f.bak` doesn't need to be commented, but I'm not sure what the intent of your many lines of code are.

You insert a comment with the '#' char, like

```
#  concatenate all files that contain the word CREDITS into a file called rsh1
find ~/2011/Fall/StudentsRecord -name "*.rec" | xargs grep -l 'CREDITS' | xargs cat > rsh1
```

Also note that you consistently use all uppercase for your search targets, i.e. CREDITS, when your sample files shows mixed case. Either used correct case for your search targets, i.e.

```
`grep -l 'Credits'`
```

OR tell grep to -i(gnore case), i.e.

```
`grep -il 'Credits'
```

Your line

```
sed -n /COURSE/p rsh1 | sed 's/COURSE NAME: //g' >> rsh2
```

can be reduced to 1 call to sed (and you have the same case confusion thing going on), try

```
sed -n '/COURSE/i{;s/COURSE NAME: //gip;}' rsh1 >> rsh2
```

This means (`-n` don't print every line by default),

```
`gip` = global substitute, 
      = ignore case in matching
        print only lines where substituion was made
```

So you're editing out the string COURSE NAME for any line that has COURSE in it, and only printing those lines' (you probably don't need the 'g' (global) specifier given that you expect only 1 instance per line)

Your line

```
 sed -e :a -e '{N; s/\n/       /g; ta}' rsh2 > rshf
```

Actually looks pretty good, very advanced, you're trying to 'fold' each 2 lines together into 1 line, right?

But,

```
sed '/COURSE/d;/CREDIT/d' rsh1 | sort -uk 1,1 | cut -d' ' -f1 | paste -d' ' >> rshf
```

I'm really confused by this, is this where you're trying to total a students score? (with a sort embedded I guess not). Why do you think you need a sort,

While it is possible to perform arithmetic in sed, it is super-crazy hard, so you can either use bash variables to calculate the values OR use a unix tool that is designed to process text AND perform logical and mathematical operations of the data presented, awk or perl come to mind here

Anyway, one solution to total each score is to use awk

```
 echo "123456 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 5 8 0 12 10 25" |\
 awk '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) { tot+=$i }; print $1 "\t" tot }'
```

Will give you a clue on how to proceed for that.

Awk has predefined variables that it populates for each file, and each line of text that it reads, i.e.

```
$0 = complete line of text (as defined by the internal variables RS (RecordSeparator)
                             which defaults to '\n' new-line char, the unix end-of-line char

$1 = first field in text (as defined by the internal variables FS (FieldSeparator)
                           which defaults to (possibly multiple) space chars OR tab char
                          a line with 2 connected spaces chars and 1 tab char has 3 fields)

NF = Number(of)Fields in current line of data (again fields defined by value of FS as 
                                                described above)

(there are many others, besides, $0, $n, $NF, $FS, $RS).
```

you can programatically increment for values like $1, $2, $3, by using a variable as in the example code, like $i (i is a variable that has a number between 2 and NF. The leading '$'
says give me the value of field i (i.e. $2, $3, $4 ...)

Incidentally, your problem could be easily solved with a single awk script, but apparently, you're supposed to learn about `cat, cut, grep`, etc, which is a very worthwhile goal.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for helping me but I need a sum directly from the file.

Comment: Try this `awk '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) { tot+=$i }; print $1 "\t" tot }'  dataFile`. If you want help, you're going to have to give us more to work with the comments of myself and others. Good luck.

Comment: This is supposed to be a learning experience, right? Think what would happen if you have two more lines just like the 2 you have shown in the same file. What will happen to the values printed? (Go ahead and try it!) What variable is being used to print the values? What assignment could you add to the code to fix this situation? Good luck!